# Select each and every unique row when an auto filter is applied?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

For example I wanted to select the unique names that i get under the filter and then send an email

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: AdvancedFilter to get unique values after AutoFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260496/vba-advancedfilter-to-get-unique-values-after-autofilter)

Comment: Use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Using the below VBA code you can do this.

```
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
```

Comment: I have data in 5 columns and need

Comment: I a need a code where there are duplicates in column D and a single mail needs to be sent to the emails in column C                                        Name Type of Contact (i.e. Main, Backup) Email Address Country
Candy Main candy@gmail.com Afghanistan
Rubin Main rubin@gmail.com Rubin
Elisa Backup Elisa@gmail.com Rubin
Hamlim Main hamlin@gmail.com Algeria
Maya Backup maya@gmail.com Algeria